# Annoying auto-transition to a new line in Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've switched from **Visual Studio** to **Visual Code** and have encountered a very annoying problem.

When I move to a new line from the current line using **ENTER**, there is no problem. The cursor moves directly under the previous line, as what I expect.

However, when I want to move to a line by clicking the mouse or using the cursor control keys on the keyboard (↑, ↓, ←, →), the cursor moves to the beginning of the line instead of under the previous line or the default tab indentation! This is very frustrating because I have to constantly press TAB or align the entire code with **SHIFT + ALT + F**. Below is showing this problem:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uZwU.gif)

Is there a solution to make the cursor always move under the previous line when I move the cursor by clicking the mouse or arrow keys on the keyboard?

I have tried installing some extensions, changing settings within Visual Code itself, but none of it has helped

Comment: I don't know how, but i just putted to parameter "Editor: Scroll Beyond Last Line" to FALSE, and it is actually works :)

Comment: My understanding is that this is by design and is part of the auto-indent facilities. It automatically trims the previous line if it only contains whitespace created by autoindent when you create a new line.